# Finding Line Numbers of Node from an XML File

Tags: c++

Am finding it tricky to find line numbers from an XML file. Using the standard XML library coming up with VS 2015. I'm writing code in C++ using Microsoft libraries.

I have an XML file like shown below:

```
 <document>
    <schemaVersion>1.0.1</schemaVersion>
    <ID-1>
       <name>Sample SCX</name>
    </ID-1>
    <ID-2>
      <date>2009-03-17</date>
      <ID-2-1>
        <mediaType>myCable</mediaType>
      </ID-2-1>
      <documentType>myOrder</documentType>
    </ID-2>
    <ID-3>
      <documentCode>1</documentCode>
      <ID-3-1>
        <name>kool</name>
        <ID-3-2>
          <id>555</id>
        </ID-3-2>
      </ID-3-1>
    <ID-3>
  </document>
```

As you see there're nodes with in nodes. And i want to get the line numbers.

For e.g., get the line number for node `documentType`. In above example, the line number is 11.
Or get the line number for node `id`.

I don't have any special XML libs, and just using MSXML lib.

Below is the code that i wrote so far.

```
for (CElementEX::ElementsT::iterator child = Element.m_Children.begin(); child != Element.m_Children.end(); ++child)
{
    LineNumber++;

    if (child->m_Name == ElementName) // here i pass string to find
        return &(*child);

    while (i < child->m_Children.size())
    {
        for (i = 0; i < child->m_Children.size(); i++)
        {
            CElementEX elem = child->m_Children.at(i);
            LineNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

What am missing is a big loop that will iterate through all the nodes, sub nodes and go to the `ElementName` am looking for. And i keep a `LineNumber` int that will be incremented until i find that.

This big loop thing is actually very confusing for me. Hope someone can guide me.

Comment: This approach breaks if you put a carriage return or two between nodes or put several nodes on the same line. I suggest using a library that records the line (and column) position when parsing the XML content rather than trying some hacky work around like this.

Comment: Why do you need the line numbers?

Comment: I need to show line numbers as part of showing error messages.
I know it's kind of an hack, but please help if you can.

Comment: Or can someone suggest me a C++ lib that can be used to get the line numbers? I need something simple that can be integrated easily and also license free.